# Firebase push notification service not working on iOS 10 from test flight build

Tags: objective-c, xcode, firebase, ios10, testflight

I’ve implemented the push notification feature with firebase in one of my application. This feature not works in  Test flight build with iOS 10 devices and also the initial popup for enable notification service not shown while installing the TF build.

FYI, I uploaded TF build from Xcode 7.2

```
#if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0
@import UserNotifications;
#endif

// Implement UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate to receive display notification via APNS for devices
// running iOS 10 and above. Implement FIRMessagingDelegate to receive data message via FCM for
// devices running iOS 10 and above.

#if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0
@interface AppDelegate () <UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, FIRMessagingDelegate>
@end
#endif

// Copied from Apple's header in case it is missing in some cases (e.g. pre-Xcode 8 builds).

#ifndef NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_9_x_Max
#define NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_9_x_Max 1299
#endif

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    // Use Firebase library to configure APIs
    [FIRApp configure];

    self.defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    /*Push Notification Implementation*/
    [self registerForRemoteNotification];

    // Register for remote notifications.
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];

    return YES;
}


-(void)registerForRemoteNotification
{

    // Register for remote notifications
    if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1) {
        // iOS 7.1 or earlier. Disable the deprecation warnings.
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-declarations"
        UIRemoteNotificationType allNotificationTypes =
        (UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound |
         UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
         UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge);
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:allNotificationTypes];

        NSLog(@"iOS 7 or Earlier");

#pragma clang diagnostic pop
    } else {
        // iOS 8 or later
        // [START register_for_notifications]
        if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_9_x_Max) {
            UIUserNotificationType allNotificationTypes =
            (UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);
            UIUserNotificationSettings *settings =
            [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:allNotificationTypes categories:nil];
            NSLog(@"iOS 8 or Later");

            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
        } else {

            // iOS 10 or later
#if defined(__IPHONE_10_0) && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_10_0
            UNAuthorizationOptions authOptions =
            UNAuthorizationOptionAlert
            | UNAuthorizationOptionSound
            | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge;
            [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter]
             requestAuthorizationWithOptions:authOptions
             completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
             }
             ];

            NSLog(@"iOS 10 or Later");

            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] setDelegate:self];
            // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
            [[FIRMessaging messaging] setRemoteMessageDelegate:self]; 
#endif
        }

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
        // [END register_for_notifications]
    }

    // Add observer for InstanceID token refresh callback.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(tokenRefreshNotification:)
                                                 name:kFIRInstanceIDTokenRefreshNotification object:nil];

}
```

Comment: Which Certificate are you exporting ? https://i.stack.imgur.com/31iV9.jpg

Comment: @Janna I export the certificate as you mentioned in the image, My problem is Notification service enable popup permission not shown in iOS 10 while installing from testflight